# Calculating and Printing a tree

Tags: c

I need to build a tree that looks like this:
[image]

So I take in 2 numbers from the user, `a` and `b`. `a` defines the number of rows, and `b` defines the starting root node value. So if i had `a`=5 and `b`=3, then we get:
[image]

I basically just print that out to the console. I am just really lost how on how to start. Could anyone give me a little push in the right direction?

Comment: 1 tip is to generate a right angled triangle first, easier that way, and might help you reason out the algorithm easier as well

Comment: Your question is too broad. As a programmer you need to to be able to split 
your problem in to smaller problems, until they can be solved one at the time.
Try something and then post a question about some specific task which didn't work 
out as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is Pascal's triangle, and the value at row n, column k is b * (n choose k) where n and k are both zero-indexed, and (n choose k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)

Once you've figured this out, then the solution to your problem amounts to writing a function `int choose(int n, int k)` and to laying out the square on the console.

The layout is the hardest part, but here's an approach:

1. First, you need to pick a width that you're going to print the number out in. Let's say it's W. Probably W = 3 will be good.
2. Second, you need to figure out how many spaces to print at the start of each line. Each row adds W + 1 width to the printed part, so you need to have (W + 1) / 2 less space before on each subsequent row, ending at 0 space at row (a - 1). That means (a - n - 1) * (W + 1) / 2 spaces beforehand on row n.
3. Third, you need to write a function `int choose(int n, int k)`
4. Finally, you just need to iterate through the rows, first printing the number of spaces determined by step 2, then printing the numbers computed using the function in step 3, making sure that they're printed using something like `printf("%-*d ", W, b * choose(n, k));` to keep them aligned.

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to "grow" the tree downwards... Given the number of rows you can figure out how many elements are in the tree and allocate an array of the appropriate size.

Then starting at the top, assuming rows numbered from 1, `down_left(x) = x + row(x)` where `x` is the array index and `row(x)` is the row number `x` belongs to. `down_right(x) = down_left(x) + 1`.

Start at the top and go down_left and down_right. Then for each element in the next row you just created do the same, except add to the row below to get the cumulative effect of the "parent" numbers.

e.g. if user asks for 3 rows and root value of 3.

You know you will need 6 array elements. Allocate 6 elements and zero them.

Row 1: Put `3` at array[0]. 
Row n: Create by looking at each element in the previous row, call it i. Then do `array[down_left(i)] += i` and `array[down_right(i)] += i`. This creates row n. Repeat.

That's the rough idea anyway, have a play and see where it gets you... :)